# Is there a pandoc for data manipulation?

Tags: data-cleaning

You know how pandocs converts markdown to HTML and pdf etc.

Is there a pandocs for data manipulation? Like from SQL to pandas and SQL to dplyr etc?

Comment: I doubt it, because converting data operations between different languages/frameworks is much more complex than converting between different output formats, and languages have operational differences which cannot always be converted.